# Vue.js object properties are "hidden" after assignment

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I can retrieve data from a Firebase database, but when I try to assign the fetched data from the database, the object properties require you to invoke a getter (I mean I can't access them after assignment)

This is the Vue instance.

Yes, I know. This is formatted weirdly, this is something that VS Code does for me...

```
export default {
    name: "Home",
    data() {
        return {
            users: []
        };
    },
    created() {
        db.collection("users")
            .get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    let user = doc.data();
                    user.id = doc.id;
                    this.users.push(user);
                    console.log(this.users);
                });
            });
    }
};
```

When I open up the console I need to click on three dots to get the actual data.

Comment: All Vue state is wrapped in getters, that's what powers the reactivity system. It is not caused by your firebase assignment. Read: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
export default {
    name: "Home",
    data() {
        return {
            users: []
        };
    },
    created() {
        db.collection("users")
            .get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                let usersArray = [];
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    let user = doc.data();
                    user.id = doc.id;
                    usersArray.push(user);
                });
                this.users = usersArray;
                console.log(this.users);
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: @AlexCsillag Hi, did you have time to check the proposed solution?